# VGAM - "propodds" in R

Tags: r, logistic, interpretation

I am trying to use "propodds"  in the VGAM function in R, but am not sure if I am doing it right and don't really understand how to analyze the output I got so far to check to see if I am using it right. Any help on how to correctly use "propodds" or analyze the output would be appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
    > fittest <-vglm(rp ~ is.native + is.male + age2 + is.debt + oh + ms + cjs, propodds, data = dummydata2)
> fittest
Call:
vglm(formula = rp ~ is.native + is.male + age2 + is.debt + oh + 
    ms + cjs, family = propodds, data = dummydata2)

    Coefficients:
(Intercept):1 (Intercept):2 (Intercept):3 (Intercept):4 (Intercept):5     is.native 
  2.827674173  -0.463602645  -0.474290665  -0.614877500  -2.514394420  -0.063546621 
      is.male          age2       is.debt            oh            ms           cjs 
  0.114052675   0.067835161  -0.058563607  -0.089420626   0.109135966   0.003937505 

Degrees of Freedom: 52000 Total; 51988 Residual
Residual deviance: 24702.04 
Log-likelihood: -12351.02 
> summary(fittest)

Call:
vglm(formula = rp ~ is.native + is.male + age2 + is.debt + oh + 
    ms + cjs, family = propodds, data = dummydata2)

Pearson residuals:
                    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
logit(P[Y>=2])  -5.1080  0.1300  0.2803  0.3016  0.3335
logit(P[Y>=3])  -0.6976 -0.5876 -0.5490  0.5937 14.7717
logit(P[Y>=4]) -13.1157 -0.5173 -0.4831  0.6080  3.0626
logit(P[Y>=5])  -4.0174 -0.4072 -0.3746  1.0167  1.2176
logit(P[Y>=6])  -0.6164 -0.5749 -0.1610 -0.1541  3.6060

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept):1  2.827674   0.079827  35.423  < 2e-16 ***
(Intercept):2 -0.463603   0.068894  -6.729 1.71e-11 ***
(Intercept):3 -0.474291   0.068901  -6.884 5.83e-12 ***
(Intercept):4 -0.614878   0.069009  -8.910  < 2e-16 ***
(Intercept):5 -2.514394   0.074892 -33.573  < 2e-16 ***
is.native     -0.063547   0.062409  -1.018  0.30857    
is.male        0.114053   0.039694   2.873  0.00406 ** 
age2           0.067835   0.024789   2.737  0.00621 ** 
is.debt       -0.058564   0.052983  -1.105  0.26902    
oh            -0.089421   0.057526  -1.554  0.12008    
ms             0.109136   0.041587   2.624  0.00868 ** 
cjs            0.003938   0.043653   0.090  0.92813    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Number of linear predictors:  5 

Names of linear predictors: 
logit(P[Y>=2]), logit(P[Y>=3]), logit(P[Y>=4]), logit(P[Y>=5]), logit(P[Y>=6])

Dispersion Parameter for cumulative family:   1

Residual deviance: 24702.04 on 51988 degrees of freedom

Log-likelihood: -12351.02 on 51988 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations: 4 

Exponentiated coefficients:
is.native   is.male      age2   is.debt        oh        ms       cjs 
0.9384304 1.1208112 1.0701889 0.9431182 0.9144608 1.1153140 1.0039453
```

A little background on my data that may help: I am trying to determine if risk preferences (variable "rp" in the code) is determined by immigration status (variable "is.native" in the code, which is a dummy variable where 0 = native and 1 = immigrant). I have a few factors that I want to control for since they may affect risk preferences [age2, is.debt, oh(owns home), ms (marital status), and cjs (current job status)]. Based on similar research the best way to analyze this is the cumulative logistic regression and they seemed to look at the proportional odds. The data came from the 2014 Health and Retirement Study which is representative of the US population over age 50. There are about 20,000 participants.

I'm not sure if my model is formatted correctly. "rp" has 6 categories - a control group, low risk tolerance (rt), some rt, high rt, substantial rt and "ignore" which is answers of "don't know" or "NA".  All other variables are dummy variables with only options for "0" or "1" besides "age2" which has 6 categories (under 50, 50-60, 60-70, 70-80, 80-90, 90+). Are these dummy variables appropriate to use or should I just use the actual answers provided by the participants?

I know the significant codes in the "summary" section tell me gender, age, and marital status are significant at the 1% significance level, but I don't understand any of the other results. Such as, what does it mean that all the intercepts are significant? Is the model as a whole significant? What is the dispersion parameter? What are the exponentiated coefficients?